# Removing a comment and try to vote up another one in under 5 seconds

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, rate-limiting, comment-voting

When i remove a comment of mine and after that directly try to upvote another one i receive the message, that a upvote for a comment is only possible every 5 seconds.

Is this a wanted behaviour?

This is reproducable. Try it yourself.

Comment: Both, afaik, count as voting actions. And you can only perform one of those every 5 seconds. So by-design I'd say.

Comment: What a mess lol! Long story short, deleting a comment is actually a vote thus bound to the votes rate limiting.

Comment: Well okay. That escalated quickly. :D Thx for the answers!